# Find by include nil object error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying hard to solve this problem but i really don't know what is happening. I have this small piece of code :

```
DiscoveredLocation.find_by_user_id(user.id, :include => [:boss_kills])
```

The models are :

```
DiscoveredLocation(id, user_id, boss_location_id)
BossKill(user_id, monster_id)
```

and associations :

```
Monster belongs_to :boss_location
Monster has_many :boss_kills

BossKill belongs_to :user
BossKill belongs_to :monster


DiscoveredLocation belongs_to :user
DiscoveredLocation  belongs_to :boss_location

DiscoveredLocation  has_many :monsters, :through => :boss_location

DiscoveredLocation  has_many :boss_kills, :through => :monsters
```

When i executed the find_by i get this error :

```
NoMethodError in BossesController#index

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
```

If i change the include option to any other model, like :monster, it works great. I'm pretty much owned by this problem :P. Maybe somebody can help me ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DiscoveredLocation model is attempting to define a nested has-many through association:

```
DiscoveredLocation  has_many :monsters, :through => :boss_location
DiscoveredLocation  has_many :boss_kills, :through => :monsters
```

I don't believe ActiveRecord can do this out of the box. There is a [nested_has_many_through](https://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through) plugin which claims to support this -- I have no idea if it would work in this case.

More discussion can be found [here](http://geoff.evason.name/2010/04/23/nested-has_many-through-in-rails-or-how-to-do-a-3-table-join/) and [here](http://kconrails.com/2010/01/28/nesting-has_many-through-relationships-in-ruby-on-rails/)

Comment: This sounds very interesting. I'm taking a closer look and will report my findings soon.

Comment: hmm, i installed the plugin and still get the same error. On second thought, i think that rails should support this association by default. A discovered_location has many boss_kills and since a monster has many boss_kills, a discovered_location has the same boss_kills through monster. This looks like a standard join using :through doesn't it ? I do the same on BossLocation Model and it works fine. I have BossLocation > has_many :users, :through => :discovered_locations. It could be how the association is set though :/

Comment: No, as I understand it nesting `has_many :through` associations is not supported. You have three associations -- the `belongs_to :boss_location`, and then two `has_many :through` associations chained together. Your best bet IMO is to use the `:finder_sql` option on the `boss_kills` association and write the query yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, however to help you out, try `DiscoveredLocation.find_by_user_id(user.id, :include => [:boss_kill])`

Lastly, are you sure you are passing a variable called user into the controller?  maybe current_user, if you are using a popular auth gem?

Comment: This change gives a Association named 'boss_kill' was not found, so i suppose boss_kills is ok. Also, yes user is actually current_user :) It's called user in this case because it's inside a function and user.id is certainly correct (i've checked nil and used :include=>:monsters and other includes with no problem).

Comment: So what is the function that is passing user, cause it's blank it appears.  Or you may have a blank record of sorts fudging up the works.  Strange things happen.  I'd like to see the whole function if this is inside another function. thanks.

Comment: It's not a problem with user for sure. But fyi, it's like :

 def self.getLocationNextBosses(user)
  DiscoveredLocation.find_all_by_user_id(user.id, :include => [:boss_location, :monsters])
 end
and getLocationNextBosses is called as is with current_user as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the intermediate tables as well, otherwise there's no way to map boss_kills to DiscoveredLocations:

```
DiscoveredLocation.find_by_user_id(user.id, :include => [:monsters, :boss_locations,:boss_kills])
```

Also, check your development log to see the query that gets generated. If possible, post it here so we can determine whether it's missing one of the intermediate tables.

Comment: Still the same error. I thought that the "has_many :boss_kills, :through => :monsters" was enough for this mapping.

Comment: had a small misconception about your data model - updating answer, try it like that.

Comment: same. I've actually tried with many models. Only when i remove :boss_kills, it works with the other models.