# No method error when executing find_by. Is this a rails bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm officially out of ideas :P I've started to think that this could be a rails problem, but most times when i think that i'm the one who makes the mistake :) I've asked this question(in another manner though) 2 times in StackOverflow and i didn't get a correct answer. So i'm trying a new approach.

There is this line :

```
DiscoveredLocation.find_all_by_user_id(user.id, :include => [:boss_kills])
```

getLocationNextBosses only executed the above line.

What could create this error message ? It seems to be part of rails implementation inside find. What do you think ? (user.id is definately correct btw).

```
NoMethodError in BossesController#index

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each

RAILS_ROOT: /Users/hthought/rails/bbg
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/association_preload.rb:125:in `add_preloaded_records_to_collection'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/association_preload.rb:243:in `preload_has_many_association'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/association_preload.rb:241:in `each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/association_preload.rb:241:in `preload_has_many_association'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/association_preload.rb:120:in `send'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/association_preload.rb:120:in `preload_one_association'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb:97:in `each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb:97:in `each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/association_preload.rb:114:in `preload_one_association'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/association_preload.rb:91:in `preload_associations'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/association_preload.rb:90:in `preload_associations'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/association_preload.rb:90:in `each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/association_preload.rb:90:in `preload_associations'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1550:in `find_every'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:615:in `find'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1900:in `find_all_by_user_id'
/Users/hthought/rails/bbg/app/models/boss_kill.rb:12:in `getLocationNextBosses'
/Users/hthought/rails/bbg/app/controllers/bosses_controller.rb:8:in `index'
```

development.log also shows :

```
  [4;35;1mBossKill Load (0.3ms)[0m   [0mSELECT `boss_kills`.* FROM `boss_kills` WHERE (`boss_kills`.monster_id IN (695794181,732497461)) [0m
  [4;36;1mBossKill Columns (11.9ms)[0m   [0;1mSHOW FIELDS FROM `boss_kills`[0m

NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each):
  app/models/boss_kill.rb:12:in `getLocationNextBosses'
  app/controllers/bosses_controller.rb:8:in `index'
  /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'

Rendered rescues/_trace (114.2ms)
Rendered rescues/_request_and_response (0.8ms)
Rendering rescues/layout (internal_server_error)
```

Comment: Post the code of your getLocationNextBosses method. We don't know what u have on line 12 and before it.

Comment: I say in the post that getLocationNextBosses executes only this line :

 def self.getLocationNextBosses(user)
  DiscoveredLocation.find_by_user_id(user.id, :include => [:boss_kills])
 end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a Rails bug?

Very unlikely.

> What could create this error message ?

Hard to tell without seeing some more code. I'd suggest posting the `User` model, `BossKill` model, and the `BossesController#index` action for a start.

Comment: Please take a look at that. It's another question on the exact same context. I post all the code there.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536473/find-by-include-nil-object-error-in-rails/4536505#4536505

Comment: Based on your model's (DiscoveredLocation) association, this include doesnt make immediate sense. I suppose the find_all_by_user_id works when you dont provide the include . DiscoverLocation and User are directly related by not with BossKill model. Try including things one model at a time by stepping thru your association one at a time.