# Getting random nil.each error in mysql2 gem when using :include in Rails's find

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, include

I'm randomly (as it seems) getting a nil.each error on my localhost. Was feeling pretty confident in the code though so I pushed it to heroku and it works fine there.

Here's my view code:

```
<h2><%=@book.name.upcase%></h2>

<br />

<% @book.chapters.each do |chapter| %>
    <h3>Chapter <%=chapter.number%></h3>
    <% chapter.verses.each do |verse| %>
        <b><%=verse.number%>)</b> <%=verse.body%>
    <% end %>
    <br /><br />
<% end %>
```

At first all I had in my controller was something like `@book = Book.find(params[:id])` and that worked fine except for the speed. Then I changed to this:

```
def show
    if params[:book_name]
        #@book = Book.find_by_sql(["select * from books where UPPER(name) = UPPER(?)", params[:book_name]]).first
        @book = Book.where(["UPPER(name) = UPPER(?)", params[:book_name]]).includes(:chapters => :verses).first
        raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, "Page not found" if @book.nil?
    elsif params[:id]
        @book = Book.find(params[:id].to_i, :include => {:chapters => :verses})
    end
end
```

Now I randomly get this error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
...
app/controllers/books_controller.rb:14:in `show'
```

One difference is heroku uses postgre and I'm using mysql.
Heroku url: http://kjv-on-rails.heroku.com/books/1
Full application code: https://github.com/tybro0103/KJV-on-Rails

**Update**
I just checked the Full Trace and realized the error occurs here:

> mysql2 (0.2.6)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:635:in
>   `select'

So the error is happening in the mysql2 gem.

**Note**
It's been brought to my attention that I have odd/redundant relations & data. I realize this, I promise! I don't believe that's causing the error though. :)

**Note**
By random here's what I mean... On some books I never see this error. On others I see 90% of the time, while yet on others I see it 50% of the time. I just hit refresh over and over and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I guess the only way to really see what I mean is to download the code yourself. My guess is no one will which means I'll start a bounty in a couple days as an incentive. :)

**UPDATE**
So the error occurs in the mysql2 adapter. Funny thing is that `@book = Book.find(params[:id].to_i, :include => {:chapters => :verses})` causes the error when running rails server. In the rails console I can run the same command all day long and it works fine. It was using webrick, but I tried switching to mongrel and got the same error. I've also tried switching from ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.2 and get the same error. It seems like maybe there is some sort of memory limit within the rails server maybe?

Comment: code looks fine, no errors raised http://kjv-on-rails.heroku.com/books/1

Comment: yeah exactly... but on my localhost i get a nil.each error... just found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536473/find-by-include-nil-object-error-in-rails

Comment: strange solution: Book has many Chapters AND Verses, and at the same time Verse belongs_to Book and Chapter. Maybe you should rebuild your architecture and make __Book__ `has_many :verses, :through => :chapters`

Comment: yeah... I know my relations are redundant... I just tried changing that, but still got the same error.

Comment: try this in your controller `@book = Book.find(params[:id])`

Comment: @fl00r uh... I've already said in the question itself that I have done that. It works that way, just slow since it makes a million queries.

Comment: i tested this using mysql on my local machine and did not have any issues.  i also noticed in your readme that you said to upload the fixtures could take around 5 minutes - in my case it took nowhere close to this and my computer is ~8 years old so its not a matter of my computer being overly powerful.  i would venture to say then that the problem is not your code but your machine and/or mysql installation.  have you tried using postgresql locally to see if the issue still persists?

Comment: @Will Ayd yeah it took about 45 secs for me to load the fixtures... just said 5 mins to be safe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHHHH... I found the trouble maker! I just downgraded mysql from 5.5 to 5.1 ...problem gone! What a pain in the @$$ that was.

It still would be nice to be able to use the latest release of mysql however. If someone can find a way to make it work using mysql 5.5 I'll mark that as the accepted answer.

Comment: do you have any code leftover from your 5.5 logs?  what select statement got generated whenever you got 'mysql2 (0.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:635:in `select''

Comment: I don't have the logs, but the generated queries are: "  Book Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `books`.* FROM `books` WHERE `books`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Chapter Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `chapters`.* FROM `chapters` WHERE (`chapters`.book_id = 1)
  Verse Load (50.4ms)  SELECT `verses`.* FROM `verses` WHERE (`verses`.chapter_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50))"